# Reversing RotateAxisAngle back to angles

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, geometry, axis

I'm trying to figure out how to reverse RotateAxisAngle to get back rotations around these arbitrary axes (or equivalent rotations that yield same net rotation, doesn't have to be identical).  Does anyone know how to do it?  I'm using MathGeoLib, but I don't see an opposite way, to return back the angles about axes, when all you have is the matrix.

Here's the forward direction code (RotateAxisAngle is from MathGeoLib):

```
float4x4 matrixRotation = float4x4::RotateAxisAngle(axisX, ToRadian(rotation.x));
matrixRotation = matrixRotation * float4x4::RotateAxisAngle(axisY, ToRadian(rotation.y));
matrixRotation = matrixRotation * float4x4::RotateAxisAngle(axisZ, ToRadian(rotation.z));
```

Now I want to get back to the degrees, about these arbitrary axes, in the same order (well, pull off Z, then Y, then X), so if I did it again, forward direction, would yield the same net rotations.

Here's the sample/matrix corresponding to that set of rotations I posted above, if it helps, on reversing back to it:

```
axisX:
x   0.80878228  float
y   -0.58810818 float
z   0.00000000  float
Rot about that axis:
30.000000   float

axisY:
x   0.58811820  float
y   0.80877501  float
z   0.00000000  float
Rot about that axis:
60.000000   float

axisZ:
x   0.00000000  float
y   0.00000000  float
z   1.0000000   float
Rot about that axis:
40.000000   float
```

That forms this matrix, which is stored to a file, and need to retrieve the rotations about above axes (without any info about rotations originally used)

```
[4][4]
[0x0]   0.65342271  float
[0x1]   -0.51652151 float
[0x2]   0.55339342  float
[0x3]   0.00000000  float
[0x0]   0.69324547  float
[0x1]   0.11467478  float
[0x2]   -0.71151978 float
[0x3]   0.00000000  float
[0x0]   0.30405501  float
[0x1]   0.84856069  float
[0x2]   0.43300733  float
[0x3]   0.00000000  float
[0x0]   0.00000000  float
[0x1]   0.00000000  float
[0x2]   0.00000000  float
[0x3]   1.0000000   float
```

Comment: Doesn't mean _to reverse it_ using the exact negative angle values on the result of the 1st rotation?

Comment: float4x4::ToEulerXYZ()  ?      
https://github.com/juj/MathGeoLib/blob/master/src/Math/float4x4.cpp

Comment: That gets euler around the unit axes, not arbitrary axes.

Comment: MathGeoLib follows the (bad, IMHO) convention that matrix is applied to vector in the order M*v, which means Mx My Mz v applies in the order rotation about Z axis, then Y axis, then X axis, which is not "XYZ" order. That begins to explain some of the difficulties of the situation. Do you want XYZ order, or do you want to determine Euler angles in the ZYX order in your code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm going to take another stab at this. My first answer was for XYZ order of rotations. This answer is for ZYX order, now that I know more about how MathGeoLib works.

MathGeoLib represents position vectors as column vectors `v = [x y z 1]^T` where `^T` is the transpose operator which flips rows to columns (and vice versa). Rotation matrices pre-multiply column vectors. So if we have a matrix `Rx(s)` representing a rotation around the x-axis by s degrees, then a rotation `Ry(t)` representing a rotation about the y-axis by t degrees, then rotation `Rz(u)` representing a rotation about the z-axis by u degrees, and we combine them and multiply with `v` as `Rx(s) Ry(t) Rz(u) v`, we're actually applying the z rotation first. But we can still work out the angles from the combined matrix, it's just that the formulas are going to be different from the more common XYZ order.

We have the upper left blocks of the rotation matrices as follows. (The fourth row and column are all 0s except for the diagonal element which is 1; that never changes in the calculations that follow so we can safely ignore.) MathGeoLib appears to use left-handed coordinates, so the rotation matrices are:

```
        [1      0      0]          [ cos t  0  sin t]          [ cos u -sin u  0]
Rx(s) = [0  cos s -sin s], Ry(t) = [     0  1      0], Rz(u) = [ sin u  cos u  0]
        [0  sin s  cos s]          [-sin t  0  cos t]          [     0      0  1]
```

(Note the position of the - sign in `Ry(t)`; it's there because we think of the coordinates in cyclic order. `Rx(s)` rotates y and z; `Ry(t)` rotates z and x; `Rz(u)` rotates x and y. Since `Ry(t)` rotates z and x not in alphabetical order but in cyclic order, the rotation is opposite in direction from what you expect for alphabetical order.

Now we multiply the matrices in the correct order. `Rx(s) Ry(t)` is

```
[1      0      0][ cos t  0  sin t]   [       cos t      0        sin t] 
[0  cos s -sin s][     0  1      0] = [ sin s*sin t  cos s -sin s*cos t]
[0  sin s  cos s][-sin t  0  cos t]   [-cos s*sin t  sin s  cos s*cos t]
```

The product of that with `Rz(u)` is

```
[       cos t      0        sin t][ cos u -sin u  0] 
[ sin s*sin t  cos s -sin s*cos t][ sin u  cos u  0] =
[-cos s*sin t  sin s  cos s*cos t][     0      0  1]

[                   cos t*cos u                   -cos t*sin u        sin t]
[ sin s*sin t*cos u+cos s*sin u -sin s*sin t*sin u+cos s*cos u -sin s*cos t]
[-cos s*sin t*cos u+sin s*sin u  cos s*sin t*sin u+sin s*cos u  cos s*cos t]
```

So we can figure out the angles as follows:

```
tan s = -(-sin s * cos t)/(cos s * cos t) = M23/M33 => s = -arctan2(M23,M33)
sin t = M13 => t = arcsin(M13)
tan u = -(-cos t * sin u)/(cos t * cos u) = M12/M11 => u = -arctan2(M12,M11)
```

If we are to implement those calculations, we need understand how the matrix is indexed in MathGeoLib. The indexing is row major, just like the mathematical notation, but indexing starts at 0 (computer style) rather than at 1 (math style) so the C++ formulas you want are

```
s = -atan2(M[1][2],M[2][2]);
t = asin(M[0][2]);
u = -atan2(M[0][1],M[0][0]);
```

The angles are returned in radians so will need to be converted to degrees if desired. You should test that result in the case when axes for the rotations Z, Y, and X are in standard position (001), (010), and (100).

If we are to reverse a rotation about non-standard axes, as in your example, the problem becomes more difficult. However, I think it can be done by a "change of coordinates". So if our rotation mystery matrix is `matrixRotation`, I believe you can just form the "conjugate" matrix

```
M = coordinateChangeMatrix*matrixRotation*coordinateChangeMatrix^{-1}
```

and then use the above formulas. Here `coordinateChangeMatrix` would be the matrix

```
[Xaxis0 Xaxis1 Xaxis2 0]
[Yaxis0 Yaxis1 Yaxis2 0]
[Zaxis0 Zaxis1 Zaxis2 0]
[     0      0      0 1]
```

where the rotation X-axis is `(Xaxis0,Xaxis1,Xaxis2)`. In your example those numbers would be `(0.808...,-0.588...,0)`. You should make sure that the rotation matrix is orthonormal, i.e., the dot product of Xaxis with itself is 1, the dot product of Xaxis with another axis is 0, and the same for any other axis. If the coordinate change matrix is not orthonormal, the calculation might still work, but I don't know for sure.

The inverse of the coordinate change matrix can be calculated using `float4x4::inverseOrthonormal` or if it's not orthonormal you can use `float4x4::inverse` but as I mentioned I don't know how well that will work.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, and thank you for the explanation to go with it, and it even nearly worked! :) This way was the right way: float4x4 mat = coordinateChangeMatrix * matrixRotation * coordinateChangeMatrixInverse;  Except for one last thing!   The values retrieved are all negative of what they should be.  Aka -30, -60, -40 when inputs were 30, 60, 40.  I can negative them both, but is there a good explanation for that?  Is it because this is going backwards or something?

Comment: Gosh, that's a relief, that it's almost right, even if it isn't exactly right! I think I know what the problem is: My calculations above are for a right-hand coordinate system. (Yet another variable in the rotation pantheon.) For a left-hand coordinate system, you negate all the signs in front of the sine functions only, or equivalently, negate the angles as you noted. I could not find mention of the handedness of the coordinate system in the MathGeoLib documentation but this means we can now suppose it's left-handed. Just reverse the signs in the formulas for s, t, u to correct.

Comment: I just edited my answer to use left-handed coordinate system, and removed uncertainty in the language.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a rotation that reverses the rotation you've got in one step, you can invert the rotation matrix. `float4x4::InverseOrthonormal` should work, and it's fast and accurate. `float4x4::Inverse` will also work but it's slower and less accurate.

If you really want to recover the angles, it goes something like this. (There are numerous different conventions, even for X-Y-Z; I think this one matches, but you may have to take the transpose of the matrix or make some other modification. If this doesn't work I can suggest alternatives.) First we follow the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Euler_angles_.28x-y-z_extrinsic.29_.E2.86.92_Rotation_matrix) for a description of the Euler Angles to Matrix conversion. In the resulting matrix, we have

```
A11 = cos theta cos psi
A21 = -cos theta sin psi
A31 = sin theta
A32 = -sin phi cos theta
A33 = cos phi cos theta
```

where phi is the rotation around the x-axis, theta is the rotation around the y-axis, and psi is rotation around the z-axis. To recover the angles, we do

```
phi = -arctan2(A32,A33)
theta = arcsin(A31)
psi = -arctan2(A21,A11)
```

The angles may not match the original angles exactly, but the rotations should match. arctan2 is the two-argument form of the arctan function, which takes into account the quadrant of the point represented by the argument, and deals correctly with 90 degree angles.

Given the way your rotations are represented, I think you may have to use the transpose instead. That's easy: you just swap the indices in the above formulas:

```
phi = -arctan2(A23,A33)
theta = arcsin(A13)
psi = -arctan2(A12,A11)
```

If neither of those work, I could take a closer look at the MathGeoLib library and figure out what they're doing.

**Update**

I neglected to take into account information about the axes of rotation in my previous answer. Now I think I have a plan for dealing with them.

The idea is to "change coordinates" then do the operations as above in the new coordinates. I'm a little hazy on the details, so the process is a little "alchemical" at the moment.  The OP should try various combinations of my suggestions and see if any of them work ... there aren't too many (just 4 ... for the time being).

The idea is to form a *coordinate change matrix* using the coordinates of the rotation axes. We do it like this:

```
axisX: 0.80878228 -0.58810818 0.00000000 0.00000000
axisY: 0.58811820  0.80877501 0.00000000 0.00000000
axisZ: 0.00000000  0.00000000 1.0000000  0.00000000
and..: 0.00000000  0.00000000 0.00000000 1.0000000
```

I have just taken the three 3-vectors axisX, axisY, axisZ, padded them with 0 at the end, and added the row `[0 0 0 1]` at the bottom.

I also need the inverse of that matrix. Since the coordinate system is an orthonormal frame, the inverse is the transpose. You can use the `InverseOrthonormal` function in the library; all it does is form the transpose.

Now take your mystery matrix, and pre-multiply it by the coordinate change matrix, and post-multiply it by the inverse of the coordinate change matrix. Then apply one of the two calculations above using inverse trig functions. Crossing my fingers, I think that's it ...

If that doesn't work, then pre-multiply the mystery matrix by the inverse of the coordinate change matrix, and post-multiply by the coordinate change matrix. Then apply one or the other of the sets of trig formulas.

Does it work?

Comment: Yeah, I need the angles as I am converting between formats and that's how they store it.

Comment: I posted two sets of formulas. One of them should work. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, however, the numbers aren't adding up.  I included in my question a sample matrix.  Perhaps the reason is that my axes are not the unit axes, they are arbitrary custom examples?  Hopefully my sample set in question will help spark a bell.  I am basically getting 0,0,value for your examples, but they don't yield the same rotation about the arbitrary axes.

Comment: Oh yeah, axes. :-) I think that may be (part of?) the problem. Offhand I don't know how to fix that. For now I would say it's best to use quaternions as an intermediate representation and the ToEulerXYZ library function, per your other post.

Comment: Unfortunately the format loses that info, when trying to convert back (only stores it as the 3 axis-angles about arbitrary axes, which are really just a rotated version of up/right/forward)).

Comment: I've updated my answer to (hopefully) take into account the "changed" axes of rotation. I think it will work. The idea is to "change coordinates" to the new system by conjugating by an appropriate coordinate change matrix. I'm not quite sure what is the appropriate coordinate change, but I've provided two suggestions in my answer, one of which will hopefully work. It's partly intuition as I haven't worked out the details yet, but please try it out so I know whether I'm on the right track.

Comment: Assuming I did it right, not getting what I expect.    So you start with the matrix I have above (in my original post) corresponding to euler rotated, then take yours and OrthoNormal (minor change to 11,12,21,22), and then do your formulas, but it's not getting the right values.  I can't tell if close or not.

Comment: One way to probe the situation to see how close or far my suggestions are is to simplify the input ... use standard rotation axes and set two out of three angles = 0. I downloaded and compiled MathGeoLib so I could take a crack at it myself but so far it has been frustrating ... my Ubuntu system libraries seem to need c++11. ?? Seems to be working now but to speed things along can you post a full forward direction program, not just a snippet?

Comment: I use visual studio 2008, but hope this helps! You end up with matrix from my sample above, ready to be reversed.  Thanks for helping!   http://www.mediafire.com/download/4wdamrqs285ar7y/ProblemReverseAnglesTest.zip

Comment: Thanks, but I think I've got it. Take a look at my other answer. Test it first with standard rotation axis, first with one non-zero angle, then two non-zero angles, then three, then with non-standard axes.